# How to fill object by Interface type and return?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following function that fills object by interface type:

```
public _fillAddModel<T>(lessonId: number, studyPeriodId: number, confirmed: boolean = false): T {
    let data: T;
    data = {
      lesson: this.substitution.lessonNumber,
      schoolStudyPeriod: GlobalModel.getSelectedPeriod().id,
      confirmed: true
    };

    return data;
  }
```

Call like this:

```
let data = this._fillAddModel<ISubstitutionModelTeacher>(1, 2, true);
let data = this._fillAddModel<ISubstitutionModelAddTeacherSubject>(1, 2, true);
```

As you can see I try to fill object by interface: `T` then continue to fill this interface after:

```
data.subsDate = this.substitution.date;
```

All interfaces extends main interface: `ISubstitutionModelAdd`:

```
export interface ISubstitutionModelTeacher extends ISubstitutionModelAdd {
  newTeacher: number;
  subsDate: string;
}

export interface ISubstitutionModelAddTeacherSubject extends ISubstitutionModelAdd {
  newTeacher: number;
  subsDate: string;
  classSubject: number;
}

export interface ISubstitutionModelAddFree extends ISubstitutionModelAdd {
  subsDate: string;
  remark: string;
}
```

My issues is to fill object by default interface `ISubstitutionModelAdd` then return object and fill this additional data by interface `T`.

Comment: So `_fillAddModel` fills in the common part and you want to be able to fill the uncommon part in the same call ?

Comment: Yes, I need fill common part: `fillAddModel` then continue to fill remaining part

Comment: Maybe somehow join objects by interface I mean join output `fillAddModel` with object `ISubstitutionModelAddFree` then continue to fill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take an extra parameter that represents the rest of the properties that you want to initialize, this parameter will contains all the properties of the generic parameter `T` minus those you pass as other arguments:

```
class Filler {
    _fillAddModel<T extends ISubstitutionModelAdd>(lessonId: number, studyPeriodId: number, otherFields: Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'lesson' | 'schoolStudyPeriod'>>): T {
        let data = Object.assign({
            lesson: this.getLessonById(lessonId),
            schoolStudyPeriod: this.getStudyPeriodId(studyPeriodId),
        }, otherFields);

        return data as any;
    }
    // Usage
    test() {
        let data = this._fillAddModel<ISubstitutionModelTeacher>(1, 2, {
            subsDate: "",
            confirmed: true,
            newTeacher: 0
        });
    }

    // Dummy methods
    getLessonById(lessonId: number): number{ return lessonId; }
    getStudyPeriodId(studyPeriodId: number): number{ return studyPeriodId; }
}
```

Comment: Excellent!, but what about to pass <T, U> then join object in function before return?

Comment: Not sure what `U` represents. Could you write a sample usage ?

Comment: I mean something this: `_fillAddModel<T, U>(properties) { let a<T>= {}; let b = <U>; let r = a.join(b); }`  Calling: `_fillAddModel<ISubstitutionModelAdd, ISubstitutionModelTeacher>() {}`

Comment: Multumesc pentru respons, prieten!

Comment: I'm thinking about it, but I am not 100% how the call would look, You need the know the properties in order to assign them in the function, you can't directly assign properties for an arbitrary `T`.  You can copy the with `Object.assign`

Comment: This part looks ugly and not easy: `otherFields: Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'lesson' | 'schoolStudyPeriod'>>): T {}`

Comment: You can assign the common part of `ISubstitutionModelAdd`, and have rest as a second parameter an object literal like i sugets above .. I don't see another solution

Comment: `otherFields: Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof ISubstitutionModelAdd>> ` would exclude all fields of the base interface .. looks a bit better maybe ? :D

Comment: Can you recommend another approach? I mean not using interfaces, or change relations between interfaces?

Comment: Easy way to set all properties in interface `ISubstitutionModelTeacher` as optional

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168302/discussion-between-titian-cernicova-dragomir-and-dooglu).